# Filtering operation is trace decreasing?

Tags: quantum-operation, locc-operation

Let $\rho$ is a bipartite state.

W is a local filtering operation that acts on a subsystem of the state  $\rho$.

After the local filtering operation $\rho$ emerges into a $\tilde{\rho}$ i.e

$\tilde{\rho}=\frac{I\otimes W \rho I\otimes W}{\mbox{Tr}(I\otimes W \rho I\otimes W)}$

Local filtering operation is trace decreasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Generally you should think of filtering as being a measurement. You're only describing the effect of one measurement outcome. There's generally a second one such that the net effect is trace preserving.

In this case, you'd be using measurement operators $\{M_i\}$ satisfying $\sum_iM_i^\dagger M_i=1$, and each achieves a transformation
$$
\rho\mapsto \frac{M_i\rho M_i^\dagger}{\text{Tr}(M_i^\dagger M_i\rho)}.
$$
For example, filtering might be described by
$$
M_0=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{bmatrix},\qquad M_1=\begin{bmatrix} \beta & 0 \\ 0 & \alpha \end{bmatrix}
$$
with $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$.

Comment: okay. thanks. got it.